# Using Crystal Reports year to date

Tags: crystal-reports

I am relatively new to using Crystal Reports. I am pulling the correct information from my database however I need to only pull the information from the beginning of the month to the current date, i.e. 09/01/2013 - 09/23/2013. Could anyone give me a snipit of code on how that would look.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: Example for the record selection]

In below figure you can add the records selection on the required field and add the condition similarly

Comment: -1: Your formula is incorrect and will only return records if the report is run on the first day of the month. Your `<=` and `>=` signs are flip-flopped.

Comment: I do accept but it was conceptual which user has understood better and added as solution.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is you need to filter the data before it is populated on reports i.e. filtering the query itself. The other option is to create new parameter for the selected field and passing the value on runtime.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205398/Crystal-Report-Filtering-Using-Selection-Parameter

Comment: Isn't there a way to use the MonthtoDate function in the formula field in order to only allow dates that are within the range?

Comment: Formulaes are meant for formatting the reports and therefore your approach will not work.

Comment: @RobbyIndian This is not true. You can use the `MonthToDate` keyword in the record selection formula and with no performance hit. CR will automatically translate it to actual dates in the query. The simplest solution is `{table.date} in MonthToDate`

Comment: Ryan I have already given solution with record selection formulae, but is there any with normal one as user is new to reports therefore I didn't provided him that much details.